# How to simplify dependency injection of generic interfaces with multiple implementations in a Java application?

Tags: java, spring, generics, design-patterns, interface

I have an interface that looks like this:

```
public interface InputsValidator<T> {
    List<MessageEnum> validator(T input);
}
```

I have multiple implementations for example:

```
@Component
class AddressInputsValidator implements InputsValidator<Address> {

    @Override
    public List<MessageEnum> validator(Address input) {
        List<MessageEnum> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        // Some actions
        return messages;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Component
class ContactInputsValidator implements InputsValidator<Contact> {

    @Override
    public List<MessageEnum> validator(Contact input) {
        List<MessageEnum> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        // Some actions
        return messages;
    }
}
```

Now, in my Spring Boot service, I need to call multiple validators. Today, if I need 10 validators I need to declare all of them:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class MyServiceApiImpl extends DelegateHelper implements UserApiDelegate {

    private final InputsValidator<Address> addressInputsValidator;
    private final InputsValidator<Contact> contactInputsValidator;
    ....
}
```

Is there an elegant way or design pattern to replace all these InputsValidator declarations of each type, with only generic one? For example

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class MyServiceApiImpl extends DelegateHelper implements UserApiDelegate {

    private final InputsValidator<T> inputsValidator; // Wrong solution
    ....
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Each validator receives a different type, so that distinction has to be propagated somehow. The bit that confuses me is that you want a generic thing, which is already `InputValidator<T>`, what else do you want different? It's worth mentioning that Spring encourages a very, very poor OO design in which all logic is in 'Services/handers/whatever`, and I wonder if you are feeling some frustration due to it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_Validation and https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/

Comment: To add to Basil's comment: You seem to have implemented your own validation mechanism. Java EE / Jakarta EE has a standard API for validation, the Bean Validation API. Spring supports this as well. It would be better to use the standard mechanism instead of re-inventing this yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question fully, but here are a few ideas.

You can group multiple validators on the same type with a class like this:

```
public class MultiInputsValidator<T> implements InputsValidator<T> {
    private final InputsValidator<T>[] validators;

    public MultiInputsValidator(InputsValidator<T>... validators) {
        this.validators = validators;
    }

    @Override
    public List<MessageEnum> validator(T input) {
        List<MessageEnum> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (InputsValidator<T> tor: validators) {
            result.addAll(tor.validator(input));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

You can write a validator class that validates a property of an object as follows:

```
public class PropertyValidator<T,F> implements InputsValidator<T> {
    private final Function<T,F> getter;
    private final InputsValidator<F> fieldValidator;

    public PropertyValidator(
            Function<T,F> getter, InputsValidator<F> fieldValidator) {
        this.getter = getter;
        this.fieldValidator = fieldValidator;
    }

    @Override
    public List<MessageEnum> validator(T input) {
        return fieldValidator.validator(getter.apply(input));
    }
}
```

And you can combine the above for a particular class, like say:

```
public class Compound {
    private Contact contact;
    private Address address;

    public Contact getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    ...
}
```

As follows:

```
@Component
public class CompoundInputsValidator extends MultiInputsValidator<Compound> {
    @Autowired
    public CompoundInputsValidator(
            AddressInputsValidator addressValidator,
            ContactInputsValidator contactValidator) {
        super(new PropertyValidator<>(Compound::getAddress,addressValidator),
                new PropertyValidator<>(Compound::getContact,contactValidator));
    }
    
}
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Spring automatically groups all the validators inside a list in this manner:

```
@Autowired
List<InputsValidator> inputsValidators;
```

This, `inputValidators` list will contain all the implementation classes of `InputsValidator`